# Disabling back button in AngularJS with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, html5-history

I want to disable back button for my application(I know this is stupid, bad user experience, against the world, even a crime !) but my client want its back button disabled :). anyway I did the following for disabling the back button.

I set a flag in `window.onpopstate` event handler like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function() { window.backClicked = true; }
```

and inside my main controller is set the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if (window.backButton) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    window.backButton = false;
                }
            });
```

**I wanted to know that is my approach bad?**

I used other popular solution like this:

```
 window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1); // or window.forward()
  };
```

but it didn't work in chrome, it didn't work for the first time and circulate between states, and `window.forward()` didn't reload the state, more precisely: If I have three states named A, B, C with respective URLs `/stateA`, `/stateB` and `/stateC` and user is in state B, he presses the back button suddenly url changes to `/stateA` and state A is loaded and url is changed to `/stateB` but state B is not loaded and url is `/stateB` but the loaded state is A.

**any fix or idea on the latter approach?**

Just a side note that I am struggling with this issue more than three days.

Comment: the problem is that there are some similar apps in the market which have disabled back button. they are mostly written in asp.net web forms which is somewhat easier to disable the back button, and the bigger problem is that in a big enterprise, a single developer does not have that much power.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if (window.backButton) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    window.history.forward();// keep redirecting to the same page
                }
        });
```

event.preventDefault() will you prevent the backward and also window.history.forward() will keep remain the same page , lets try this!!

Comment: I am not really convinced what is the extra benefit of adding `window.history.forward()`, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: As you know forward() method loads the next URL in the present history list.
This is the same as clicking the "Forward button" in your browser, like you know history.go(1).
it clearly says you will keep forward as the result is you will remain on the same page.
Notes: it will support all the All popular browsers.

Comment: without using `window.history.forward()` I stay in the current url too, Am I doing something wrong ?